# Test for difference in proportions between sample and subsample

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a sample of companies classified into 9 groups by industries. In each industry percentage of firms with particular characteristic is different. Is there any way to test whether subsample (companies in some industry) have different proportion of firms having this characteristic then overall sample (here all firms in all industries)? So if I know that 45% manufacturing companies pay dividends while 50% of all companies (including manufacturing companies) pay dividends, how can I say whether this difference is significant?

Edit: This question is not a duplicate of "How can I test the difference between a population proportion and sample proportion?", since I do not deal with population and I want to test difference in proportions between sample (all firms) and subsample (firms from some industry).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test the difference between a population proportion and sample proportion?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50112/how-can-i-test-the-difference-between-a-population-proportion-and-sample-proport)

Comment: Try explantion of your study objectives and hypotheses. Just read tests for difference in proportions.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question, since sample vs subsample is not the same as population vs sample. In this case we shouldn't be treating the 50% as a population figure free of sampling variation.

Comment: You need to be clear about "all industries" and indusry-specific data. At indusry-level you can check whether manufacturing companies proportion paying dividend differs significantly.It is different story when you are interested in difference across industries. Have a relook into body text and if necessary rectify to meet your ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is a [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test). From wikipedia: "The chi-squared test is used to determine whether there is a significant difference between the expected frequencies and the observed frequencies in one or more categories."